# I need to select all divs that end up with '__tienda' class. All elements have different id's

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I need to select all divs that end up with '__tienda' class. All elements have different id's.

how do i select all divs that end up with __tienda class?

all classes are different just end up with __tienda from sass design.

this is a blueprint and that's the reason all divs are different, they all have different messures

```
<div id="1piso" class="pisoplano">
            <div class="titulo">
                <h1>1er Piso</h1>
                <h2>Total Center</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="plano">

                <div id="escalera-top-izq" class="escaleras">
                    <div class="puerta"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="escalera-medio-a" class="escaleras">
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="escalera-medio-b" class="escaleras">
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>`your text`
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                    <div class="grada"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="sshh_top">
                    <div class="mujeres">
                        <div class="esquina">
                            <div class="puerta"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="bano_01" class="bano">
                            <img src="images/inodoro.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div id="bano_02" class="bano">
                            <img src="images/inodoro.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div id="bano_03" class="bano">
                            <img src="images/inodoro.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hombres">
                        <div class="puerta"></div>
                        <div class="bano">
                            <img src="images/inodoro.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bano">
                            <img src="images/inodoro.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="servicios">servicios</div>
                <div class="accesorios">accesorios</div>
                <div class="opticas">ópticas</div>
                <div class="ropa_ca">ropa caballeros</div>
                <div class="accesorios_2">accesorios</div>
                <div class="tecnologia">tecnología</div>
                <div class="tecnologia_2">tecnología</div>
                <div class="servicio_tecnico">servicio técnico</div>

                <div class="e-top">
                    <div id="e7" class="e-top__tienda">E7</div>
                    <div id="e6" class="e-top__tienda">E6</div>
                    <div id="e5" class="e-top__tienda">E5</div>
                    <div id="e4" class="e-top__tienda">E4</div>
                    <div id="e3" class="e-top__tienda">E3</div>
                </div>

                <div class="d-mid">

                    <div class="d-mid__der">
                        <div id="d8" class="d-mid__der__tienda">D8</div>
                        <div id="d7" class="d-mid__der__tienda">D7</div>
                        <div id="d6" class="d-mid__der__tienda">D6</div>
                        <div id="d5" class="d-mid__der__tienda">D5</div>
                        <div id="d4" class="d-mid__der__tienda">D4</div>
                        <div id="d3" class="d-mid__der__tienda">D3</div>
                        <div id="d2" class="d-mid__der__tienda">D2</div>
                        <div id="d1" class="d-mid__der__tienda">D1</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="d-mid__izq">
                        <div id="b6" class="d-mid__izq__tienda">B6</div>
                        <div id="b7" class="d-mid__izq__tienda">B7</div>
                        <div id="b8" class="d-mid__izq__tienda">B8</div>
                        <div id="b9" class="d-mid__izq__tienda">B9</div>
                        <div id="b10" class="d-mid__izq__tienda">B10</div>
                        <div id="b11" class="d-mid__izq__tienda">B11</div>
                        <div id="b12" class="d-mid__izq__tienda">B12</div>
                        <div id="b13" class="d-mid__izq__tienda">B13</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="d-izq">
                    <div id="d16" class="d-izq__tienda">D16</div>
                    <div id="d15" class="d-izq__tienda">D15</div>
                    <div id="d14" class="d-izq__tienda">D14</div>
                    <div id="d13" class="d-izq__tienda">D13</div>
                    <div id="d12" class="d-izq__tienda">D12</div>
                    <div id="d11" class="d-izq__tienda">D11</div>
                    <div id="d10" class="d-izq__tienda">D10</div>
                    <div id="d9" class="d-izq__tienda">D9</div>
                </div>

                <div class="enfermeria">
                    <div class="enfermeria__local">
                        <div class="cruz">
                            <img src="images/cruz.svg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bloque-a"></div>
                    <div class="bloque-b"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="e-der">
                    <div id="e1" class="e-der__tienda">E1</div>
                </div>

                <div class="m-der">
                    <div id="m10" class="m-der__tienda">M10</div>
                    <div id="m9" class="m-der__tienda">
                        <div class="cabecera">
                            <h4>M9</h4>
                        </div>
                        <img src="images/automovil.svg" alt="">
                        <hr>
                        <img src="images/automovil.svg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="b-der">
                    <div id="b5" class="b-der__tienda">B5</div>
                    <div id="b4" class="b-der__tienda">B4</div>
                    <div id="b3" class="b-der__tienda">B3</div>
                    <div id="b2" class="b-der__tienda">B2</div>
                    <div id="b1" class="b-der__tienda">B1</div>
                </div>

                <div class="puerta-ingreso">
                    <div class="puerta-ingreso_a">
                        <div class="ala_a"></div>
                        <div class="ala_b"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="puerta-ingreso_a">
                        <div class="ala_a"></div>
                        <div class="ala_b"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="c-izq">
                    <div id="c8" class="c-izq__tienda">C8</div>
                    <div id="c9" class="c-izq__tienda">C9</div>
                    <div id="c10" class="c-izq__tienda">C10</div>
                    <div id="c11" class="c-izq__tienda">C11</div>
                    <div id="c12" class="c-izq__tienda">C12</div>
                    <div id="c13" class="c-izq__tienda">C13</div>
                    <div id="c14" class="c-izq__tienda">C14</div>
                </div>

                <div class="ca-mid">

                    <div class="ca-mid__izq">
                        <div id="c1" class="ca-mid__izq__tienda">C1</div>
                        <div id="c2" class="ca-mid__izq__tienda">C2</div>
                        <div id="c3" class="ca-mid__izq__tienda">C3</div>
                        <div id="c4" class="ca-mid__izq__tienda">C4</div>
                        <div id="c5" class="ca-mid__izq__tienda">C5</div>
                        <div id="c6" class="ca-mid__izq__tienda">C6</div>
                        <div id="c7" class="ca-mid__izq__tienda">C7</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ca-mid__der">
                        <div id="a5" class="ca-mid__der__tienda">A5</div>
                        <div id="a6" class="ca-mid__der__tienda">A6</div>
                        <div id="a7" class="ca-mid__der__tienda">A7</div>
                        <div id="a8" class="ca-mid__der__tienda">A8</div>
                        <div id="a9" class="ca-mid__der__tienda">A9</div>
                        <div id="a10" class="ca-mid__der__tienda">A10</div>
                        <div id="a11" class="ca-mid__der__tienda">A11</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="a-der">
                    <div id="a1a" class="a-der__tienda">A1-A</div>
                    <div id="a1b" class="a-der__tienda">A1-B</div>
                    <div id="a2" class="a-der__tienda">A2</div>
                    <div id="a3" class="a-der__tienda">A3</div>
                    <div id="a4" class="a-der__tienda">A4</div>
                </div>

                <div class="m-der_abajo">
                    <div id="m8" class="m-der__tienda">
                        <div class="cabecera">
                            <h4>M8</h4>
                        </div>
                        <img src="images/automovil.svg" alt="">
                        <hr>
                        <img src="images/automovil.svg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div id="m7" class="m-der__tienda">M7</div>
                    <div id="m6" class="m-der__tienda">M6</div>
                    <div id="m5" class="m-der__tienda">M5</div>
                </div>

                <div class="m-abajo">
                    <div id="m3" class="m-abajo__tienda">M3</div>
                    <div id="m2" class="m-abajo__tienda">M2</div>
                </div>

                <div class="m-abajo-medio">
                    <div id="m4" class="m-abajo-medio__tienda">M4</div>
                    <div id="m1" class="m-abajo-medio__tienda">M1</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Don't know where to start

Answer (score 2):

If the elements only have a single class, or that class is always last in the list, you can use an [attribute suffix selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
div[class$="__tienda"]{
    background: red;
}
```

The same selector is [supported by jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

```
jQuery('div[class$="__tienda"]').css('background','red');
```

Comment: I need to call those divs into jquery

Comment: @JuanostandswithRussia jQuery uses the same selectors.